# How to load mp3 audio file more than 4GB using pydub Python

Tags: python, pydub

I try to load audio using pydub python. However, when the audio file more than 4GB, python cannot load the audio if less than 4GB pydub can load and process the audio. The audio format in MP3 file format.

```
for i in glob('audio_folder/*mp3*'):
     sound = pydub.AudioSegment.from_mp3(i)
```

however, it return error as below :

CouldntDecodeError: Unable to process >4GB files

therefore, is there any python library or how to load audio with more than 4GB size.

currently im using python with 64 bit and latest version.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved this problem by using mp3 first on google site, the process using librosa. i did not found any solution how to load audio more than 4GB size.